# Slow query for update/delete sql statements

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, sql-update

In mysql there are lot of slow queries, only related to update and delete statements. The tables have 2 index columns and not heavily indexed tables. Each table having 30K records on average.

Please give your suggestions on how to overcome the slow queries related to update and delete queries.  These kind of queries:

```
DELETE FROM <table2> 
 WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID 
                FROM <table1> WHERE ID2=100);
```

...or:

```
UPDATE <table1> 
   SET <colmunname>=0 
 WHERE id=1001;
```

Comment: Are they large heavily-indexed tables?

Comment: Your question is too broad to answer specifically. It could be anything from the query to the connection. Are you able to post the queries so we can take a more in-depth look at them?

Comment: The tables have  2 index columns and not heavily indexed tables. Each table having 30K records on average.

Comment: Need more information on your specific scenario.  What is the where clause you are using to update or delete?  In that where clause, what are the properties of the columns involved?  How many records are in the table and what are the indexes?

Comment: DELETE FROM <table2> WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM <table1> WHERE ID2=100);

UPDATE <table1> SET <colmunname>=0 WHERE id=1001;

These kind of queries.

Comment: For ex: ID is indexed, ID2 is indexed.

Comment: @Karthick - and how long do those queries take?

Comment: Sorry i don't have the accurate exceution time, it could be between 30 secs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being that the tables are indexed, my first suggestion is to update the statistics for the tables using [ANALYZE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/analyze-table.html):

```
ANALYZE TABLE table1, table2
```

But beware:

> During the analysis, the table is locked with a read lock for MyISAM, BDB, and InnoDB.

Comment: What benefit Analyze will give on slow queries?

Comment: @Karthick: `ANALYZE TABLE` will update the statistics (including indexes) for the designated table(s), which the optimizer then uses to make decisions about how to access & ultimately work with the data.

Comment: Thanks Ponies. 
When i ran Analze table <tablename>, all i see is this

Table->table name Op->analyze Msg_type->status Msg_text->Ok

so this will help and reduce the overhead of slow queries?

Comment: Also, the slow queries occur @ a particular time – How can we determine what happened at this time to make the database so slow?

Comment: @Karthick: You'll want to read about MySQL query profiling using the [MySQL Query Profiler](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/using-new-query-profiler.html) to see if slowdown is due to server load/etc.

Comment: @Karthick: No prob, let me know if you find what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that your problem only exists on updates and deletes tells me that you are probably indexing too much.

Indexes will vastly reduce the time that certain queries take, but will require extra work when inserting, updating, and deleting entries from your tables. Try eliminating indexes on columns that are often getting updated, especially if they don't often appear in a `where` clause in your SQL queries.

Comment: Indexes are used for more than just the WHERE clause - SELECT, JOIN and ORDER BY can leverage index use if the optimizer sees fit to.

Answer (score 0):

Managing indexes and foreign key relationships both incur overhead during update and delete operations.  I would restore a copy of your prod db on a dev server, drop all foreign key constraints and all expect your primary key indexes and see the performance difference.  Then you can add back your indexes until you have a better performance balance for your app.

Comment: Foreign keys do not impact speed of queries; they only constrain data for the designated column(s).

Answer (score -1):

First and foremost: Use [stored procedures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure).

Next: If your db has optimizing capabilities -> use them.

Finally: Consider using no-relational dbs like [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) or [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/) instead ;-)

Comment: Sorry am allowed to use MySQL, i will add your point in future DB selections.